# Launching an application in Apple Business Manager

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ipados, apple-vpp

I have a free application for iPad in the app store. Now I need to add the application to Apple Business Manager so that one organization that wants to use the application can automatically deploy it on more than 90 iPads

I have read many articles that talk about how you can do this even before publishing the application and these applications are private. But in my case, the application is not private and is free and available in the app store. I also found information that you can add an application through the app store connect in the “Pricing and Aviability” section, but this section is not displayed for me as in the link below

[“Pricing and Aviability” I don't have this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDAVB.png)

Comment: If your app is public then you don't need to do anything. The organisation simply uses Apple Business Manager to "purchase" 90 copies of your app. ABM can be used to obtain App Store apps and private apps.

Comment: thanks, understood it! My problem was  that the region was not added and the organization did not see my application in ABM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.